# How to loop through multiple worksheets with a sub that is already looping?

Tags: excel, vba

So I've got this sub I've pieced together that runs through all tabs in my workbook looking for a specific name, then copies all that data into a single sheet, at the next empty row.

Basically combining a bunch of similar sheets with same column format.

So my question is how do I modify this to loop through multiple groups of sheets?  Right now, this is coded to only work for sheets named like "Group1" and copy into a single sheet called "raw_Group1".

How do I modify to then also look for "Group2", ... "GroupN"?  The grouping name is not actually numbered, but something like "people" "stuff" "orders" etc.  Each group has a different column structure and multiple sheets that I'm trying to combine.

```
Sub copy_Group1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Destws As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim wsLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long

'This keeps the screen from updating until the end, makes the macro run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'defines an existing "Raw_Group1" worksheet instead of creating a new one
Set Destws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Group1")

'clears sheet first, leaving headers
Destws.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

'Fill in the start row.
StartRow = 2

'Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the summary worksheet.
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If LCase(ws.Name) Like "group1*" Then

    'Find the last row with data on the summary and source worksheets.
    Last = LastRow(Destws)
    wsLast = LastRow(ws)

    'If source worksheet is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow, copy the range.
    If wsLast > 0 And wsLast >= StartRow Then

        'Specify the range to place the data. Four options for specifying the range
        ''Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1") 'whole block of columns
        ''Set CopyRng = ws.Range("A1:B" & LastRow) 'specific columns, to the last row
        ''Set CopyRng = ws.Range("B1").CurrentRegion 'uses the current block of data
        Set CopyRng = ws.Range(ws.Rows(StartRow), ws.Rows(wsLast)) 'Set the range starting at row2

        'Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary worksheet to copy all the data.
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > Destws.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
            "summary worksheet to place the data."
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        CopyRng.Copy ' This statement copies values and formats.

        'paste values only
        With CopyRng
            Destws.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
            .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
End If
Next

ExitTheSub:
Application.Goto Destws.Cells(1)

'filter: turns off then on (resets)
If Destws.AutoFilterMode Then Destws.AutoFilterMode = False
Destws.Range("A1").AutoFilter

'AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
Destws.Columns.AutoFit

'turns screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: modify this line `If LCase(ws.Name) Like "group1*" Then`

Comment: that seems to just change which group the rest of the if statement is looking for.

I'm asking about adding a higher level loop to iterate group1, group2, groupn, etc.

I can certainly repeat the entire thing, but looking for a cleaner code.  I'm still trying to learn how to set up this syntax

Comment: Use a case select for each of the different groups.  You can even do the case LCase(ws.Name) like "People1*" .

Comment: like adding my list of group names as an array or something, then iterate through from 1st to last, running through the code (defining destination and copy/paste each matching sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Consider generalizing your workbook processing for each group by setting up parameters into your macro with following changed lines. If certain groups need specific processing use conditional `If` or `Select Case` blocks for those particular parameter values:

```
Sub copy_Group(group_name As Variant, dest_sheet As Variant)

    ...
    Set Destws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(dest_sheet)    
    ...
    If LCase(ws.Name) Like group_name & "*" Then
    ...

End Sub
```

And then in another macro iteratively pass all pairs of group names and destination sheets when calling your above macro. Add accordingly if you need other parameters like *Start_Row* and even use other data structures (i.e., collection, dictionary) instead of anonymous nested array.

```
Sub RunLoop()
    Dim var As Variant

    For Each var In Array(Array("group1", "Raw_Group1"), Array("people", "ppl_dest"), _
                          Array("stuff", "stuff_dest"), Array("orders", "order_dest"), _
                          Array("other", "other_dest"))
        Call copy_Group(var(0), var(1))
    Next var

End Sub
```

Of course there's no reason you cannot embed this loop in previous macro but this may help in code organization, even abstraction between the steps.

Comment: hey, i implemented your advice, but still seems to not be passing the variable names through

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...@parfait...So I tried your advice here.  It kinda works, but doesn't seem to be passing the 'group name' (the 1st 'type') to the first if-statement

```
Sub RunLoop()
    Dim var As Variant
    For Each var In Array( _
        Array("stuff", "Raw_stuff"), _
        Array("people", "Raw_people"), _
        Array("orders", "Raw_orders"))
        Call copy_Group(var(0), var(1)) 'calls sub listed below
    Next var
End Sub
```

=====================

```
Sub copy_Group(group_name As Variant, dest_sheet As Variant)

Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Destws As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim wsLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long

'This keeps the screen from updating until the end, makes the macro run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'defines an existing worksheet instead of creating a new one
Set Destws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(dest_sheet)

'clears sheet first, leaving headers
Destws.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

'Fill in the start row.
StartRow = 2

'Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the summary worksheet.
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(ws.Name) Like group_name & "*" Then

        'Find the last row with data on the summary and source worksheets.
        Last = LastRow(Destws)
        wsLast = LastRow(ws)

        'If source worksheet is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow, copy the range.
        If wsLast > 0 And wsLast >= StartRow Then

            'Specify the range to place the data. Four options for specifying the range
            ''Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1") 'whole block of columns
            ''Set CopyRng = ws.Range("A1:B" & LastRow) 'specific columns, to the last row
            ''Set CopyRng = ws.Range("B1").CurrentRegion 'uses the current block of data
            Set CopyRng = ws.Range(ws.Rows(StartRow), ws.Rows(wsLast)) 'Set the range starting at row2

            'Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary worksheet to copy all the data.
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > Destws.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                "summary worksheet to place the data."
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            CopyRng.Copy ' This statement copies values and formats.

            'paste values only
            With CopyRng
                Destws.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:
    Application.Goto Destws.Cells(1)

'filter: turns off then on (resets)
If Destws.AutoFilterMode Then Destws.AutoFilterMode = False
Destws.Range("A1").AutoFilter

'AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
Destws.Columns.AutoFit

'turns screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```